# Bootstrap CSS Calendar align months

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really hope there is an easy fix for this. Basically on full screen I want two months to show in a colum, on smaller devices it shifts to 1 column (i am using .col-md-6 for this), with 3 rows total showing 6 months. This works if each div is the same size. The issue arrises when there is a month with less "blocks of days"

see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rrryqzzppql858/months.png?dl=0

is there some sort of vertical-align css that can be used in bootstrap to fix this???

Here is my code:

```
<?php
            $date = date_create("2015-01-01");
            $date_end = date_create("2015-07-01");

            while ($date < $date_end):?>
                <div class="col-md-6 month_border">
                    <?php echo "<h2>".date_format($date,'F')."<small>".date_format($date,'Y')."</small></h2>"; ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                        //date_format($date,'w') Day of week: 0 = Sunday
                        //date_format($date,'t') Number of days in current month
                        $weekday = date_format($date,'w');
                        $total_days = date_format($date,'t');
                        $days28 = 0;
                        if ($total_days == 28) {$days28 = 1;}
                        for ($day_block = 0 - $weekday + 1; $day_block <= $total_days + $days28; $day_block ++):?>
                            <?php if($day_block > 0 AND $day_block <= $total_days):?>
                                <div class="col-7split day_block" id="day_block-<?php echo date_format($date,'n')."-".$day_block; ?> "
                                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="@mdo">
                                    <div class="row border bg-info">
                                        <?php echo $day_block; ?>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row border">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 shift_text">
                                            <?php if($day_block != 3) { echo "N"; }  ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 compliment_text nopadding hidden-print">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            <?php else:?>
                                <div class="col-7split day_block">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php date_modify($date,"+1 months"); endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Try adding a `<div class="clearfix">` after every second column to force the next column (e.g. march) to start on a new line. If that doesn't do the trick I think we need to see some code :)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help nor did it move any of my divs. Probably due to bootstraps row function?

Comment: I guess we really need code in that case (I assumed you had all `col-md-6` columns in a single row, so in total 12 months * 6 columns = 72 columns in a 12 column layout)

Comment: I've tried to create the html output from that (apparently I have php installed) and added bootstrap's css. I am missing some CSS I think as everything occurs on its own line. If you also add the HTML and CSS output I can take a small look